# Multiple queries with PDO extension

Tags: php, pdo

I'm developing an application and to do so, I organize my page as the following

- Bloc php: inwhich I put my queries
- Bloc html: in which I have a form to insert data and a table listing
  data
- Bloc php: inwhich I unset queries

I have this piece of code (first bloc):

```
<?php
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

//------Query used to insert data
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {

    $insertSQL=$pro->prepare("INSERT INTO position (ID, DESCRIPTION) VALUES(:a, :b)");
        $insertSQL->bindValue(':a', $_POST['ID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $insertSQL->bindValue(':b', $_POST['DESCRIPTION'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $insertSQL->execute();
}

//------Query used to update data
if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form2")) {

    $updateSQL=$pro->prepare("UPDATE position SET DESCRIPTION=:a WHERE ID=:b");
        $updateSQL->bindValue(':a', $_POST['DESCRIPTION'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $updateSQL->bindValue(':b', $_POST['ID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $updateSQL->execute();
}
//------Query used to display list of inserted data in a table
$rs = $pro->prepare("SELECT * FROM position ORDER BY DESCRIPTION");
$rs->execute();
$row_rs = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

I would like to know if there is a problem with the code above

Answer (score 0):

Looks more or less fine to me, are you having any problem with it?

You're not checking for errors. Both prepare() and execute() return **false** if there's any error. But if you configured PDO to throw exceptions on errors, then you don't have to check this return value.

Since you're binding values, it might be a bit quicker to do this:

```
$updateSQL->execute([':a'=>$_POST'DESCRIPTION'], ':b'=>$_POST['ID']]);
```

You can do that instead of calling bindValue() for each parameter. The PDO::PARAM_STR and PDO::PARAM_INT types don't do anything.

```
$rs = $pro->prepare("SELECT * FROM position ORDER BY DESCRIPTION");
```

This seems a little odd to choose to sort by the description. Not necessarily an error, just not what I would expect to be the sort order.

Comment: That code works, but since I use that approach in all pages, I was told that there is a huge quantity of duplicate codes!